# How to detect which ViewController is being popped on popViewController func override?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have sublassed **UINavigationController** to conform my needs and use case. There in order to detect **back** action I have overriden method that is properly called on desired action:

```
var popViewController: ((UIViewController) -> Void)?

    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }
```

I would like to check which VC is being currently popped in order to compare it further to evaluate some properties.
First thing I tried is to add **var** that will be changed inside this override method.

```
var popViewController: ((UIViewController) -> Void)?
```

But I have no further clue what should be done.
Is that even possible to do here?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you have that variable with a closure type, you can check the view controller that is being popped right in the override method without needing any stored properties:

```
override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
    let popVC = super.popViewController(animated: animated) // this is the view controller that will be popped
    // Do what ever check you want to do here
    return popVC
}
```

Comment: I used this clousure to assign and pass the returned VC to another class - thus I’ve got no Idea go to do it now.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, the result of calling `func popViewController(animated: Bool)` on a `UINavigationController` returns the popped controller if any was popped.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller